# Training while loop in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I've attempted converting a Python-side training loop to Tensorflow to (hypothetically) make the code run faster - not having to pass control over to cpu constantly. However, I can't manage using `tf.while_loop`.

Here's the code that works:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

x, y = load_iris(True)
x = RobustScaler().fit_transform(x)

shape = (10, 10)
max_epochs = 1000


graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

x = x.astype(np.float64)


# Construct graph
with graph.as_default():
    weights = tf.get_variable(
        'weights', shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer, dtype=tf.float64
    )
    curr_epoch = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=())

    with tf.name_scope('data'):
        data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
        data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
        data = data.repeat(max_epochs)
        data = data.batch(1)
        data = data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    with tf.name_scope('update'):
        update_op = make_update_op(weights)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


sess.run(init)

for i in tqdm(range(max_epochs)):
    for _ in range(x.shape[0]):
        sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={
            curr_epoch: i
        })

np_weights = sess.run(weights)
print(np_weights) # Correctly prints an array of 150's.
```

Now, if I create an update function to pass `tf.while_loop`, an error is thrown.

```
def make_update_op(w):
    return w.assign(
        w + 0.001
    )

# In the code above:
update_op = tf.while_loop(lambda _: True, make_update_op, (weights,), maximum_iterations=x.shape[0])

# No inner loop:
for i in tqdm(range(max_epochs)):
    sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={
        curr_epoch: i
    })
```

> Line 22, in make_update_op
>       `return w.assign(`
>   AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

I don't quite understand what is happening even after reading the documentation. `weights` is a `Variable` after all. What could be done to correctly make the training loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all that was missing was the fact that one cannot assign to a variable inside a loop as [Vlad pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707514/7089239). Instead, one can return the new value of a variable.

```
def make_update_op(w):
    return w + 0.001

new_w = tf.while_loop(lambda _: True, make_update_op, (weights,), maximum_iterations=x.shape[0])
update_op = weights.assign(new_w)
```

To use more variables one would need to return the same amount from the function and unpack them in Python, but the principle is the same.

```
def make_update_op(w, d):
    return w + 0.001, d

new_w, _ = tf.while_loop(lambda *_: True, make_update_op, (weights, data), maximum_iterations=x.shape[0])
update_op = weights.assign(new_w)
```

Comment: @Vlad What do you mean? This produced the correct result and also worked for a more complex task.

Comment: Put instead of `(weights, )` two variables, e.g. `(var1, var2)`. It won't work

Comment: @Vlad And observe what? That's what I did, input the weights and training data simultaneously.

Comment: when you become more experienced in TF, return here to admit that I was correct! Good luck, brother! (p.s. still won't work for more than one variable/chunk of data at once!)

Comment: @Vlad What can I say but the full algorithm produced a clear solution with the Iris data set and threw no errors :D maybe you're right, would not be the first time I'm wrong, but just appealing to experience doesn't fly far either.

Answer (score 0):

The tensor that you're trying to assign a new value within a while loop is a result of a sequence of multiple operations-tensors (operation is node in the graph, while tensor is a directed edge). In particular, the while loop will produce:

`Variable/Read-->while/Enter-->while/Merge-->while/Switch-->while/Identity`

What you're trying to assign here is a tensor `while/Identity`.

`tf.while_loop` is usually used to iterate over the dimensions of a tensor (also over the  `None` - the unknown dimension). You're trying to iterate over the variables that are fully defined. You don't need to create a `tf.while_loop` for that. Just create operations that update each variable and group these operations together:

```py
update_ops = [w.assign(w + 0.001) for w in weights]
update_op = tf.group(update_ops)
```

Now, when you execute the `update_op` with `tf.Session()` interface it will update all variables.

Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1, 2), dtype=tf.float32))
v2 = tf.Variable(2*tf.ones((1, 3), dtype=tf.float32))

update_ops = [w.assign(w + 0.001) for w in [v1, v2]]
update_op = tf.group(update_ops)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('before update:')
    print(v1.eval(), v2.eval())
    print('after update:')
    sess.run(update_op) # <-- update your variables
    print(v1.eval(), v2.eval())

    # before update:
    # [[1. 1.]] [[2. 2. 2.]]
    # after update:
    # [[1.001 1.001]] [[2.001 2.001 2.001]]
```

Comment: I have purposefully simplified this example. The proper loop includes many more operations. In addition, the loop is to be run in the order of thousands of times. I have been warned to not construct operations like this in Python loops. Are you suggesting doing just that?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding of how TF graph mode works. In graph mode you first create operations and then you execute them. My Python loop creates these operations that I'll be later executing using Session interface. The person who advised you not to use Python loops has probably meant to avoid as much as possible execution of a Python code and use TF API instead. The creation of operations is irrelevant for this.

Comment: Any update of any variable is an operation. You don’t have any other way to update the variable without creating an operation that does it. If you want to assign different values each time use placeholder and feed to it the value by which you want the variable to be incremented/assigned.

Comment: I do understand what it means to create operations and then execute them. That's precisely the reason for my question. Is it not advisable to avoid creating tens of thousands of duplicate operations on a graph? Example source: [How not to program a tensorflow graph](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/how-not-program-tensorflow-graph.html) (this comment belongs above, but I had to redo because of edit restrictions)

Comment: Yes, but I imagine there being a more elegant way of doing a set of operations sequentially than creating every single one of them unrolled. I want to re-use the current value each iteration, hence the term "training loop".

Comment: The correct way of doing it as I provided. But if you look at your code, what you've tried to do is exactly what I did (only incorrectly :-) ) because you also create the `assign` operation for each variable within while loop.

Comment: I can't say I'm sure, but the `tf.while_loop` might not unroll the operations. Nevertheless, I got it working.

Comment: Your code won't work when you pass more than one variable to the `while_loop`.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, but it did. With modifications of course.

Comment: Also note that for each assign that you do at the end you're creating a sequence of operations-tensors (at least 9 operations!). While in my case it is only ONE operation - the same that you do at the end `update_op = weights.assign(new_w)`. Good luck!